# How to stop pyautogui when internet is slow and resume the previous program code

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have a question about Pyautogui. I want to click on a button/link/image, but in my country the Internet speed is very slow. So I'm trying to delay the program. But sometimes it doesn't work. The program clicks on the link/image/button before it appears on the website. That's why I cannot continue or the whole program fails.

Is there any way the program can locate if the button/link/image is displaying or not? If it is not displaying, it should wait for 30 more seconds or 1 minute. That's how I want my program to work every time. I really want to solve this issue. I hope you will reply.

Answer (score 0):

This may be tricky if you are looking at a bunch of different webpages all with different content. But if you know a specific image or link text that must be there, you should be okay.

max_wait below is so the program doesn't loop endlessly. Make it as big as you want.

For a specific image you know has to show up in the page, you can try

```
import time
import pyautogui

found_image = False
max_wait = 120

x = time.time()
while (found_image == False) and time.time() - x < max_wait:
    if (pyautogui.locateOnScreen('my_png.png') is not None):
            found_image = True

if found_image: do_main_test()
```

For text, you can use pyautogui to select all...

```
import time
import pyautogui
import pyperclip

x = time.time()
found_text = False
max_wait = 120

while (found_text == False) and time.time() - x < max_wait:
    pyautogui.click(150, 150) # or wherever is in the window
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
    pyautogui.click(x=150, y=150)
    lines = pyperclip.paste()
    found_text = needed_text in lines
    if not found_text: sleep(5) # this is so pyautogui isn't continually highlighting etc.

if found_text: do_main_test()
```

I don't know about tracking buttons, but I hope the text and image examples are useful. And of course you can specify running `do_main_test()` only if `found_text` and `found_image` are true.